# AlignIO gives 'AssertionError' when reading emboss alignment files

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, assertion, fasta, sequence-alignment

I have been stuck on a problem for three days... searched everywhere, posted on [Biostar](http://www.biostars.org/post/edit/87226/), still waiting for EMBL to respond to emails... would make a bounty if I had more rep.

After aligning sequences with EMBOSSwin `needle()` (pairwise global alignments) I get alignment files in `pair` format, with a `.needle` file extension. I want to use [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) to read these alignments for later analysis.

I use `AlignIO.read(open('alignment.needle'),'emboss')` following the instructions in [Biopython's AlignIO wiki](http://biopython.org/wiki/AlignIO) but I keep getting an `AssertionError`.

***My code:***

```
>>> from Bio import AlignIO
>>> alignment = AlignIO.read(open("data/all/out/pair1_alignment.needle"), "emboss")
```

***My error:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\Bio\AlignIO\__init__.py", line 423, in read
    first = next(iterator)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\Bio\AlignIO\__init__.py", line 370, in parse
    for a in i:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\Bio\AlignIO\EmbossIO.py", line 150, in __next__
    assert seq.replace("-", "") != ""
AssertionError
```

***Example Alignment File:***

Download the alignment file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/clxmrsr750xern3/pair1.needle)

[image: Picture of alignment file]

***Versions:***

- *Windows 7*
- *Python version 2.7.3*
- *Biopython version 1.63*
- *EMBOSS version 2.10.0-0.8*

***Clues:***

I suspect this may be related to a warning message I kept getting when actually making the alignments, which was outputted by EMBOSS `needle()` function:

```
Warning: Sequence character string not found in ajSeqCvtKS
```

Comment: To state the obvious, Biopython's error means that your FASTA file has at least one empty sequence (a string of zero or gaps). Could you post your FASTA file?

Comment: Thank you for reading @David, here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3bw9zpiwb0nqz3/pair1_aligned.fasta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate post on BioStars, http://www.biostars.org/p/87226/#87399

This appears to be down to a subtle change in the EMBOSS output. You have an extremely old version, EMBOSS version 2.10.0 (February 2005), and your output file has lines like this:

```
gag             1288 --------------------------------------------------   1287
```

Using a newer version of EMBOSS (e.g. 6.3.0), gives lines like this:

```
gag             1287 --------------------------------------------------   1287
```

The Biopython parser is expecting the latter for alignment sections with no letters (e.g. when one sequence is much longer than the other), where the start and end coordinates agree. Please update your copy of EMBOSS, and then the parser should be happy. The current EMBOSS release is version 6.5.0.

Comment: My goodness that was it... an old version of EMBOSS! Good grief.. I feel quite silly now, but thank you incredibly much for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're passing the wrong format file to Biopython. An explanation follows.

#### Formatting

The format of the file you've linked to is `srspair` (see the header of `pair1_aligned.fasta`). It's worth noting that this is *not* the [FASTA format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) - that's an entirely different format.

Delving into the [source of Biopython's `EmbossIO`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.AlignIO.EmbossIO-pysrc.html#EmbossIterator), we can see that the `EmbossIterator` (which is called by `AlignIO.read` when the format is `'emboss'`) is only meant to handle the formats `pair` and `simple` (see [Alignment formats](http://emboss.sourceforge.net/docs/themes/AlignFormats.html#pair) for an explanation of the various formats).

#### Solution

If you export EMBOSS's output in the `pair` format (then call `AlignIO.read` as you have before), that should solve your problem.

Comment: The error persists! But thank you so much for the insight.

I did what you said by making the output format as "pair" and even changed the output file extension to .needle. But still the AssertionError is returned.

Comment: Here is the new alignment file in "pair" format and .needle extension: http://bit.ly/18CPpAK

Comment: I replied on your duplicate question on Biostars, http://www.biostars.org/p/87226/#87399 - you are using an extremely old version of EMBOSS (from 2005) which produces slightly different output which the Biopython parser does not handle. Please update your EMBOSS and try again.